# Access VBA to open, edit and save Excel doc

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access DB to open, edit and save an Excel doc that works fine the first time run but if I try to alter more than one file (or the same file twice) it fails with "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Cells' of object '_Global' failed"

If I close the DB then re-open it, it again works fine for the first file altered.

Although I am not new to VBA I would say that I am a novice.  Here is a snippit of the code I am using:

```
    Code:
        'Open spreadsheet and make it visible
        Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        strInputFile = varItem
        xl.Workbooks.Open strInputFile
        xl.Visible = True

        'Trying to get row count here but not working yet
        'Set myRange = xl.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C")
        'lRowCount = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA("Sheet1").Range("C:C")
        'lRowCount = xl.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(C, C))
        'Debug.Print lRowCount
        'strMyRange = "C:C"
        'lRowCount = xl.WorksheetFunction.CountA(strMyRange)
        'Debug.Print lRowCount
        'lRowCount = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks(strInputFile).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C"))
        'Debug.Print lRowCount

        'Make the changes
        j = 0
        If Left(strFile, 4) = "xxxx" Then 
            myPath = "\\a\path\for\xxxx"
            If InStr(1, strFile, "IQ") Then
                For i = 1 To 500 'Row count not working yet
                    If InStr(1, Cells(i, "C").Value, myVariable) > 0 Then
                        Cells(i, "B") = "New Value"
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If

'Clean up
xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
Set objInputFile = Nothing
```

Comment: In which line the execution fails?

Comment: If InStr(1, Cells(i, "C").Value, myVariable) > 0 Then

Comment: Frankly I don't know why it works at all. Looks like this code was copied from Excel. In Access direct calls like Cell should not work. Use variables like `xl.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "C")`

Comment: Thanks Sergey.  I will try your suggestion and post the results when my meetings are over.

Comment: Don't forget the second `Cells` in the row below that, and don't forget to save the file using the `.Save` method on the `Workbook` object.

Comment: That worked perfectly Sergey.  Thanks for the tip. Another question about the commented out section in the code snippit I originally provided, I can't get the row count to return anything but a 1 and for the life of me all the googling I do isn't helpful.  Can ylou suggesxt a method for that please?

Erik - Thanks for looking out! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Excel VBA code for using in Access should be modified. You cannot use direct calls of Excel library methods like `Cell`. Declare variables for Excel.Application, Workbook and Worksheet and use them for referencing worksheet cells. Avoid using Activate methods. So, in your case the code will be like this:

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRowCount As Long

Dim myRange As Excel.Range

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
strInputFile = varItem
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(strInputFile)
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

lRowCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Make the changes
j = 0
If Left(strFile, 4) = "xxxx" Then
    myPath = "\\a\path\for\xxxx"
    If InStr(1, strFile, "IQ") Then
        For i = 1 To lRowCount
            If InStr(1, ws.Cells(i, "C").Value, myVariable) > 0 Then
                ws.Cells(i, "B") = "New Value"
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
End If

wb.Save
'Clean up
xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
```

Don't forget to add a reference to Microsoft Excel library

Comment: Thanks again Sergey!!  This works perfectly with only one minor change.  I had to put () around the variable in Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open (strInputFile).  No big deal but wanted to mention it for potential future viewers of this post.

I also clicked the up arrow of this answer but since I am brand new to this site apparently my votes don't count yet.  :-)

Comment: Yes, of course () needed here, I edited the answer. If answer worked for you, accept it, a green check mark will appear below the vote counter